# Why threads run sequentially instead of simulatenously in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

The threads in the following code don't seem to run simultaneously. However if I change the `number` to 1 million or add a `Thread.sleep(50);` into the loop it runs simultaneously. Making the thread sleep produces homogeneous results while increasing `number` to one million makes each thread prints 50+ lines before switching to other thread. What is the exact reason for this?

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
    int number = 4;
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    RunnableDemo(String name) {
        threadName = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("----------");
        for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();

    }

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo("Thread-1");
        RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo("Thread-2");

        R1.start();
        R2.start();
    }
}
```

This is the output produced by the code when `number` is 4:

```
Starting Thread-1
Starting Thread-2
----------
Thread: Thread-1, 4
Thread: Thread-1, 3
Thread: Thread-1, 2
Thread: Thread-1, 1
----------
Thread: Thread-2, 4
Thread: Thread-2, 3
Thread: Thread-2, 2
Thread: Thread-2, 1
```

Comment: Your test is flawed, and there's no guarantee that this result would always occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your machine has a single processor. Only one thread can run at any one time. If multiple processes are running they each receive a slice of time on the processor and will then be swapped out by some scheduling algorithm.

In your case when the number is 4 a thread can complete its work before being swapped out. Once done any other thread in the waiting state can run.

- T1 > starts > executes > terminates
- T2 > starts > executes > terminates

When you increase the number to a million a thread can execute only part of its work in the time allocated by the scheduler. Once this time is up it will be swapped out by the scheduler and another thread in the waiting state will run.

- T1 > starts > executes for time x > moved to waiting state
- T2 > starts > executes for time x > moved to waiting state
- T1 > resumes  > executes for time x > moved to waiting state
- T2 > resumes  > executes for time x > moved to waiting state
  ......
- T1 > terminates
- T2 > terminates

Simarily, when you request your thread sleeps for x then another thread can be moved to the running state.

http://tinyurl.com/o8f3ogx

Comment: Does this mean my machine has single processor?

Comment: No you can run many threads on the same processor, and have been able to do this since at least the 1960s.

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println` is *buffered*. You cannot therefore use it to test thread simultaneity.

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: You could have a static array of a numeric type, into which you write thread-specific data. Have an `int` for the array index which you increment on each write. `int` is atomic in Java so will be safe. There's probably a simpler way though. Let's wait for some other comments.

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't neccessarily switch after each instruction. It is perfectly possible for a thread to execute entire loop before switching to another. Adding sleep prolongs the execution and increases likelihood of context switch.